# Good way to generate GUIDs on app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, guid

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good way to generate GUIDs on python google app engine. I feel like there is a simple way that people are using, what would you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

The [uuid module](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) should be available.

Why do you need uuids?  Usually they're necessary to make really unique primary keys, but GAE's datastore essentially ought to be taking care of that for you.

Comment: Unique values come handy e.g. when generating nonce or, say a payment reference when talking to external API-s.

Answer (score 5):

Code example using the [uuid](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) module:

```
from uuid import uuid4

print(uuid4())

# Output: 7d720c5a-b3e9-455e-961c-0e37b330b098
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import uuid

print(uuid.uuid4().hex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the module is available in Google App Engine, check out Python's [uuid](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance they are guid's for things you're storing in the datastore?

If so, I believe object.key is a GUID

Comment: Key objects are composites of several components (app ID, kind name, key or id); they're not GUIDs.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be a GUID?  Maybe I have the definition of a GUID wrong, I thought they were simply globally unique ID's.  If I composite App ID (globally unique among apps) with kind (unique with an app) and key (unique within a kind), wouldn't that be globally unique?

Comment: I *think* the problem for the OP may be that they are guessable - so a malicious user could easily guess other keys if they have one. GUID's don't guarantee that a randomly picked GUID will not match something in your app, but it at least decreases the odds massively. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html

Comment: @NickJohnson I have been using keys as UID's, would that be a problem?